# Bearer Token Authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Trying to use bearer token based authentification in simple .Net Core Web API project. Here is my `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMvc();
//---
const string secretKey = "mysupersecret_secretkey!123";
SymmetricSecurityKey signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
//---
const string audience = "Audience";
const string issuer = "Issuer";
//---
TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidIssuer = issuer,

    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = audience,

    ValidateLifetime = true,

    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    AuthenticationType = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
};
//---
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
    AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
});
```

Also i add `AuthorizeAttribute` to controllers action

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

But when  try to send get request with header
`Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]`
i get exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Bearer
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.
```

So what is this 'authentication handler'? Where i need to set this handler?

Comment: Can you please share your entire `Configure` method?

Comment: Shure, http://pastebin.com/TgRkHNZk


app.UseSimpleTokenProvider - is a Simple Token Endpoint registration, i found it here: https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, the order of the middleware matters: they are executed in the same order as they are registered. Here, `app.UseMvc()` is called before the JWT bearer middleware, so this can't work.

Put `app.UseMvc()` at the end of your pipeline and it should work:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
    AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
});

app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: This is not working anymore as it's obsolete. I'm still hunting for a solution.

Answer (score 6):

For **.NET Core 3.0** you would need:

In `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = issuer;
        options.Audience  = audience;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    });
```

In `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`:

```
// Add it after app.UseRouting() and before app.UseEndpoints()! 
// Order of middlewares is important!
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

PS: To omit authentication scheme indication in `[Authorize]` attribute you could set the default authentication scheme in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in `AuthenticationOptions` options:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```