# Authenticating an ASP.NET Core app with OWIN bearer token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, owin

I am trying to authenticate an ASP.NET Core web API application with an existing SSO solution developed in ASP.NET Web API 2. The SSO app uses OWIN/ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and authenticates the users by producing a bearer token. The JWT token generation/validation logic of ASP.NET Core is pretty different from the OWIN-based one, and I can't make them fit together.

Up to now I could only find an answer in [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2079234.aspx?How%20to%20share%20Bearer%20Tokens%20between%20ASP%20NET%204%20x%20and%20ASP%20NET%205%20applications%20) thread, but is out-dated and incomplete.

Is there any way to authenticate the users of the ASP.NET Core app's users with the bearer token generated by such an SSO app? A solution with the least modification to the existing OWIN app would be preferable.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708266/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I can't seem to find any docs on how to manage to an Owin token. I had to abandon this...did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no @mikeo

Comment: Bummer. Sounds like it may not be possible. I'll keep you posted if I ever figure it out.