# Asp.Net Core Web Api and ReactJS: authentication with external login provider without identity

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, oidc-client

Is there a clear and simple way to use OAuth login providers in a ReactJS and Asp.Net Core Web API project?
I am looking for a solution without Identity and Razor pages. Only ReactJS and Asp.Net Core Web API.
And do we need the oidc-client library for this?

Comment: Did you discovered a solution to your problem? If you find one, could you please include a link to it?

Comment: Have a look at this article - It only shows Google, but it is very detailed and helped me a lot: https://medium.com/mickeysden/react-and-google-oauth-with-net-core-backend-4faaba25ead0
Github repo: https://github.com/mickeysden/dotnet-core-react-oauth-example

Answer (score 1):

In case you are referring to [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/):

#### React app

The react app probably wants to initiate the authentication, get hold of the [access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) which needs to be included in requests to the API, as well as refresh the access token once it is expired. You don't strictly need a library for that, but it makes your life easier, especially if you use one specific to react, like [React OIDC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oidc), which is a wrapper for the oidc-client.

An example for including the token in API requests when using [axios-hooks](https://github.com/simoneb/axios-hooks) can be found in the [Authentication and token refresh](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-hooks-authentication-zyeyh) example. See [bearer token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) for further information.

#### Web API

To handle the access token provide by the react app, you can add make use of the [JWT bearer authentication middleware](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/). Guides for integrating the middleware can be found in
[Protecting an API using Client Credentials](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#adding-an-api)
or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708266/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core).

For more details you could have a look at the [ASP.NET Core - Authentication & Authorization Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhfvbl_KbWo&list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a solution that includes WebAPI, No Razor Pages, No MVC, Pure web api. And External Authentication like google authentication with a simple ReactJS app. And I like to know its necessary to use oidc-client or it can be done with simple fetch requests.

Comment: @RashidMousavyKhoshrou  were you able to find what you wanted if so please let me know. I am still looking for something like this